# Search a value in another table if doesnt exist in the current

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table and I want to search if there is a value inside a column. In case it doesnt exist I want to search it in another table.
I tried this :

```
 SELECT *,
    CASE(WHEN student = 'ted' THEN 'ted'
    ELSE ( SELECT student
           FROM  dbo.class2
           WHERE student= 'ted')) END AS ISOK 
    from dbo.class1
```

So if `dbo.class1.student` isnt 'ted' the `ISOK` column will take the value from `dbo.class2.student`.

Although the above query is wrong because it returns more values.

I am pretty sure that the approach I am trying to do is wrong.

Comment: The above query is wrong because it is syntactically incorrect.  You should put working syntax in the question.  Sample data and desired results would help.  What should the results look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you pls try this ?

```
SELECT
       NVL(a.student, b.student) ISOK
FROM dbo.class1 a 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.class2 b ON a.student=b.student
```

Full outer join will ensure you get all the data from both tables(matching + a.non matching + b.non matching).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. Although I do not want to see if the columns have nulls. I am trying to see if the student 'ted' is in class1 and if its not search in class2. In case that it exists in any of the two tables ISOK column will take the value 'ted'

Comment: Thank you too. Now, Could you pls this sql for 'ted'? `NVL` is to ensure data coming from either class1 or class2. This will show 'ted', if both class1 & class2 has ted, if class1 has 'ted' but class2 doesnt, if class2 has 'ted' but class1 doesnt. And this will return nothing if ted is not found in any of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You were close but I think this is what you are looking for. The fact that they are in different tables really doesn't matter to the CASE, just the JOIN:

```
SELECT *, 
Case WHEN class1.student = 'ted' THEN 'ted'
ELSE class2.student='ted'
END as ISOK
FROM class1
join class2 on class1.student = class2.student
```

Comment: I think else in case when doesnt allow to apply a condition like class2.name = 'ted'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if a particular student is in the tables, use `exists`.  I would think something like this would be useful:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from class1 c1 where c1.name = 'Ted')
             then 'class1'
             when exists (select 1 from class2 c2 where c2.name = 'Ted')
             then 'class2'
        end) as which_table
```

The value is `NULL` if the name is in neither table.